# Correct way to pass reference as argument into a class

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, reference

I'm trying to keep reference of another object in a class, so i'm using pointer as member. What is the best way to pass reference and what is the difference between them.

```
class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite();
    void SetTexture(Texture * const& texture);
    void SetTexture(Texture & texture);
private:
    Texture *m_texture;
};
```

void SetTexture(Texture * const& texture) or 
void SetTexture(Texture & texture)  ?

I don't want to change a texture inside the Sprite class that's why i'm trying to use const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly not `void SetTexture(Texture* const&);`.
While it works, passing small trivial types, like pointers, by reference to constant is a pointless pessimisation.

`void SetTexture(Texture&);` makes sense if there must be a texture. `void SetTexture(Texture*)` would be more appropriate if the texture is optional.

Of course, if the recipient never modifies the texture, that should be reflected in the signature, and also in the member, by marking the `Texture` `const`.

Answer (score 0):

1) to answer your question, you should use a pointer if it's going to be kept outside the callers stack.  IE, if the Sprite class is created within a calling function or class, then you can (and should) use a reference.

2) If you're going to use a pointer, and a const pointer, you should make your member variable const too.

Comment: Texture is created outside the class, i'm just want to use it without a copy in Sprite class. I'm usually use void (Texture & texture){m_texture = &texture}; Just wondering if i'm doing right.

Comment: The nice thing about references is that the compiler will yell at you if you are doing it inncorectly.  So the general best advice these days is to use them always until the compiler says you can't.  (that's a *very* broad rule, but correct more often than not)